# Topology generated by the circles on the plane with their centers on a line

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Question: Let $S$ be the collection of all circles on the plane which have their centers on the X-axis. If $S$ is a subbasis for a topology $T$ on $\Bbb R^2$, describe the open sets in $(\Bbb R^2, T)$.

Thoughts: The question is are all singletons going to be generated by the basis hence giving us the discrete topology? I think yes. For any singleton $x$ you can construct a pair of circles that intersect at $\{a,x\}$ and another pair that intersect at $\{x,b\}$. Then $x$ is the intersection of both and is thus open in the topology. Hence the discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the topology cannot be discrete: Note that any circle centered on the $x$-axis that passes through a point $(x, y)$ also passes through $(x, -y)$, and if $(x, y)$ is not on the $x$-axis (that is, if $y \neq 0$) then these points are distinct.

Your argument shows, however, that each of the sets $\{(x, \pm y)\}$ is open in the determined topology $T$.

> So the sets in $T$ are precisely the arbitrary unions of sets $\{(x, \pm y)\}$. For $y = 0$ these are singletons and for $y \neq 0$ these are pairs of points.

Comment: So I guess this means that all pairs of points $\{(x,-y), (x,y)\}$ are open. I guess this means the open sets will look something like this: you can have any collection of points above the axis as long as you also include their exact reflections under the axis. Moreover the entire axis is open.

Comment: That's correct. Another way of putting it is that the open sets are precisely the sets symmetric about the $x$-axis, that is, the sets that are fixed by the reflection $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$ across the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the help!